# Отобразить двумерную матрицу и заполнить ее C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть ComboBox, в нем размеры матрицы от 1 до 10. Как реализовать, чтоб при выборе размера(из СomboBox) формировалась двоичная матрица, и выводились автоматически столбцы и строки матрицы нужного размера, которые можно было бы ее заполнить

Comment: как сформировать эту матрицу?

Comment: т.е. в combobox указаны размеры матрицы. к событию combobox надо подключить обработчик. а матрица чем заполняется? код нужен на С#?

Comment: да на c# матрицу сам заполняешь. последовательность должна быть такая нажали на combobox(там 1,2... ) выбрали например 3, на экране должно образоваться что-то вроде таблицы с 3строками и 3столбцами, которые мы заполняем  сами, не в коде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Width="600" SizeToContent="Height">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MatrixSize}" 
                  SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Matrix}" Height="250"
                  HeadersVisibility="None"  RowHeaderWidth="0"
                  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

```
partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public MainWindow() {
        this.MatrixSize = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
    public IList MatrixSize { get; private set; }
    public object Matrix { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        var size = (int)e.AddedItems[0];
        this.UpdateMatrix(size);
    }

    void UpdateMatrix(int size) {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("c" + i, typeof(string)));
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            var r = dt.NewRow();
            for (var c = 0; c < size; c++)
                r[c] = "hello";
            dt.Rows.Add(r);
        }
        this.Matrix = dt.DefaultView;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Matrix"));
    }
}
```

Comment: у меня подчеркивает INotifyPropertyChanged,(partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged) пишет :не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен. public IList MatrixSize  (IList подчеркивает), PropertyChangedEventHandler и DataTable

Comment: к using'ам надо добавить using System.ComponentModel;